# TypeError with PAMIE

Tags: python, pywin32, pamie

I am getting a TypeError with a very simple script on PAMIE, and I'm not sure what I can do. I had found an answer suggesting that the library, `pywin32` might not have set a `self` argument for this particular method (`getElementsByTagName`) but I don't know for sure, as I don't know where to find the definition of it.

```
from  PAM30 import PAMIE

ie = PAMIE()
ie.navigate('google.com')
ie.getButtons()
ie.quit()
print 'done'
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\pamie1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from  PAM30 import PAMIE
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PAM30.py", line 678, in getButtons
    return self.getElementsList("input", filter)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PAM30.py", line 939, in getElementsList
    elements = self._ie.Document.getElementsByTagName(tag)
TypeError: getElementsByTagName() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Here's the offending line in `PAM30`

```
elements = self._ie.Document.getElementsByTagName(tag)
```

where `_ie_` is

```
self._ie = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('InternetExplorer.Application')
```

I'm using Windows 7x64 with Python2.7 32bit

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use `from cPAMIE import PAMIE`?

Comment: @César I get `ImportError: No module named cPAMIE`

Comment: Weird, is it PAMIE 2.0? I was following this [tutorial](http://pamie.sourceforge.net/tutoriala.html)

Comment: @César nah, it was 3.0, I got from SourceForge, I believe. But you say that 2.0 works still then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sourceforge bug link](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3562879&group_id=78018&atid=551954)

"Workaround" seems to be enable Compatibility View (`Tools > Compatibility
View settings > Display all websites in Compatibility View`).

it is a bug of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Work around - Change in PAMIE30

```
elements = self._ie.Document.getElementsByTagName(tag)
```

to

```
elements = self._ie.Document.body.all.tags(tag)
```

This will work without the need to use Compatibility View!

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line:

`elements = self._ie.Document.getElementsByTagName(tag)`

to

`elements = self._ie.Document.Body.getElementsByTagName(tag)`